# Nuxt UI 3: Table Checkbox for Select All does not work(?)

Tags: user-interface, nuxt3

I am developing a GUI with Nuxt UI 3 and use the table function .
There is a checkbox there to select individual rows. This is working quite well so far. In the header of the table there is a checkbox to select all rows of the table at the same time. Unfortunately this has no effect. I want to select rows and further process the data. Does somebody has any idea?

Here is the template.

```
 <UTable v-model="selectedRows"
              :columns="columnsTable"
              @select="selectTableRow"
              :rows="filteredRows"
              :ui="{ td: { base: 'max-w-[18rem]' }, th: { base: 'whitespace-nowrap' } }"
              class="research-table__table-content"
      >
```

Here is the watch function that responds for individual selected rows but not for selectAll

```
 watch(selectedRows, (newVal) => {
  singleview = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newVal));
  selectedobjects = singleview.map(d => d["Identifier"]);
});
```

Thanks!
Gordon